# Objective-C Google Web Albums API - Strange error when trying to upload image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gdata, picasa

I'm using the Objective-C version of the API.

I've copied the code from the example project almost exactly, but am
getting this error every time I try to upload a picture:
"failedWithStatus:400 data:Photo data must not be empty.".

Here's my code:

```
- (void)uploadToPicasa
{

   // make a new entry for the photo
   GDataEntryPhoto *newEntry = [GDataEntryPhoto photoEntry];

   // set a title, description, and timestamp
   [newEntry setTitleWithString:@"Title!"];
   [newEntry setPhotoDescriptionWithString:@"Description!"];
   [newEntry setTimestamp:[GDataPhotoTimestamp timestampWithDate:
[NSDate date]]];

   // attach the NSData and set the MIME type for the photo
   UIImage *earth_image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"earth.jpg"];
   NSData *earth_data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(earth_image, 1.0);

   [newEntry setPhotoData:earth_data];

   NSString *mimeType = @"image/jpeg";

   [newEntry setPhotoMIMEType:mimeType];

   // the slug is just the upload file's filename
   [newEntry setUploadSlug:@"earth.jpg"];

   // make service tickets call back into our upload progress
selector
   GDataServiceGooglePhotos *service = [self googlePhotosService];

   SEL progressSel =
@selector(ticket:hasDeliveredByteCount:ofTotalByteCount:);
   [service setServiceUploadProgressSelector:progressSel];

   // Get URL for Picasa
   NSURL *uploadURL = [GDataServiceGooglePhotos
photoFeedURLForUserID:@"CORRECT_USERNAME"

albumID:nil

albumName:nil

photoID:nil

kind:nil

access:nil];

   // insert the entry into the album feed
   GDataServiceTicket *ticket;
   ticket = [service fetchEntryByInsertingEntry:newEntry
                                     forFeedURL:uploadURL
                                       delegate:self

didFinishSelector:@selector(addPhotoTicket:finishedWithEntry:error:)];

   // no need for future tickets to monitor progress
   [service setServiceUploadProgressSelector:nil];
}

// progress callback
- (void)ticket:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket
hasDeliveredByteCount:(unsigned long long)numberOfBytesRead
ofTotalByteCount:(unsigned long long)dataLength {

   NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", numberOfBytesRead /
dataLength]);
}

// photo add callback
- (void)addPhotoTicket:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket
    finishedWithEntry:(GDataEntryPhoto *)photoEntry
                error:(NSError *)error {

   if (error == nil) {
       NSLog(@"SHOULD BE UPLOADED MAYBE");
   } else {
       NSLog(@"THERE WAS AN ERROR");
   }
}

- (GDataServiceGooglePhotos *)googlePhotosService {

   static GDataServiceGooglePhotos* service = nil;

   if (!service) {
       service = [[GDataServiceGooglePhotos alloc] init];

       [service setShouldCacheResponseData:YES];
       [service setServiceShouldFollowNextLinks:YES];
   }

   // update the username/password each time the service is requested
   NSString *username = @"CORRECT_USERNAME";
   NSString *password = @"CORRECT_PASSWORD";
   if ([username length] && [password length]) {
       [service setUserCredentialsWithUsername:username
                                      password:password];
   } else {
       [service setUserCredentialsWithUsername:nil
                                      password:nil];
   }

   return service;
}
```

I used a breakpoint to confirm that NSData is not nil, and is the
image in question, so I'm not sure what "failedWithStatus:400
data:Photo data must not be empty." could mean.  Please help!

Comment: Can some one send me code for this. I am not able to even start as I get the code for Mac support not iOS. Also, I do not understand the integration for Google API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Instead of using below method:**

```
 NSURL *albumURL = [GDataServiceGooglePhotos
                       photoFeedURLForUserID:username albumID:kGDataGooglePhotosDropBoxAlbumID
                       albumName:nil photoID:nil kind:nil access:nil];
```

//  to fetch the album url use this one:

```
NSURL *albumURL =
[NSURL URLWithString:kGDataGooglePhotosDropBoxUploadURL]
```

//  where

```
kGDataGooglePhotosDropBoxUploadURL = "https://photos.googleapis.com/data/upload/resumable/media/create-session/feed/api/user/default/albumid/default";
```

I tried in my app and its working perfect...

You can find this url in gdata api also.

Comment: CAn you send me code. I am not able to understand where from to start even. Tried lot of samples but some have one file missing and other has some another. need this urgently please help.

Comment: this is too old code now this api is deprected... you need to use new api after integrating with api to upload photo you can use same url to upload photo may be..

Comment: I am able to do authentication login through Google plus api and get the username too but I am not able to get the client secret and secret key for upload.

Comment: I am done with Oauth,getting the Oauth object.Now i have to upload images but i don't want user to enter their username and password that '[service setUserCredentialsWithUsername:uname password:pwd]' take as they have already gone through Oauth.What is alternative way to do this?